# Python not creating sqlite3 database

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

Hello there i am just working with sqlite3 in python (3.9) and have the following basic command.

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect(r'C:\python\pythonCode\NewDB.db')
cursor = conn.cursor()
sql = '''create table students (
    id int,
    name text,
    username text)'''
cursor.execute(sql)
cursor.close()
```

i dont get any errors when i run i cannot see any db file in the C: location in the connect()

Can someone point me in the right direction please.

Answer (score 2):

*This code seems fine to me* - but by the behaviour you describe, **it sounds as if your application is not getting sufficient rights** to create the file: you are telling your code to create a file within your C:\python directory.

**I would suggest running your Python script as administrator** [run CMD as admin and then `python3 file.py`]. If you don't want to go down this route, then change the database directory to something like your desktop to avoid any privilege issues.

I hope this solves your error! Let me know.